# Cheering Japanese (volleyball) team (ゴーリゴーリ)

Tags: katakana, sports

Watching Volleyball World Cup on TV now, I started to wonder where does the cheering 「ゴーリゴーリ」 come from? Seems to be independent of which team serves, but is more loud when Japanese hold the ball.

Is it used in other sports or specific to volleyball?

Comment: 「ゴリ」っていうニックネームの人がいるとか。。。

Comment: @Shoko Indeed, why not an answer?

Comment: ほんとにいるんだぁ・・・知りませんでした。(バレーボール見てないんで…) (^^ゞ

Comment: @macraf I think [sports] is a better tag name than [sports-vocabulary], since it can be used more generally, not only for questions about vocabulary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(credit to [Shoko](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/9831/shoko) for hint)

ゴリ is a nickname of [Kunihiro Shimizu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunihiro_Shimizu) [清水邦広](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B8%85%E6%B0%B4%E9%82%A6%E5%BA%83)